# correct verb to be used with "aim"

Tags: vocabulary

is it correct to say to "meet aims"? I know we can say she fulfilled or achieved her aims , but can I also say " she met her aims"?

Comment: My aim is to win the game. I aim to win the game. So, no, one doesn't meet aims, one meets expectations of others. I fulfilled my aims.

Answer (score 0):

I feel to some extent this is just a personal preference but to my ears 'she met her aims' would be an unusual construction for a native speaker of British English.

Perhaps the reason it sounds odd is that by definition an 'aim' is something you never actually meet. It's always ahead of you. I would say 'she achieved her ambitions', 'she met her targets', 'she fulfilled her plans', 'she attained her objectives', all those sound natural to me, but 'she met her aims' doesn't. However it isn't formally incorrect and if you did say it to me I would know exactly what you meant, so I wouldn't worry too much about it ;)

I would say 'she met her mother', 'she met her fate' and 'she met her match'. Those are all idiomatic and sound natural. I'm English living in England, others may differ on this one.

Comment: "much of what Wagner was trying to achieve (for the moment, irrespective of whether he met his aims) was already in place" - (En) Corps Sonore: Towards a Feminist Ethics of the ‘Idea’ of Music in Recent French Thought - Sarah Hickmott, Merton College, University of Oxford - A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy (2017)

Comment: I wrote some of the clunkiest English ever written in my PhD thesis ;)

Answer (score 0):

A scarce few use

> she met her aims

So, yes, some may consider it ok. But it is definitely not idiomatic and very rare.
My first intuition was that it may be easier to encounter the phrase when someone or something else ***meets her aims***, but I must have been biased by the phrase ***[meet someone's needs/expectations/etc](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/meet-a-need-demand-requirement-condition-etc)***

However, there is quite a variety of [verbs that go with ***aims***](https://inspirassion.com/en/v/aims) so I am sure you will find an [alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_VERB%20her%20aims%2C%20met%20her%20aims&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bachieve_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhad_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccomplish_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bachieving_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpursue_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bachieved_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfurther_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwere_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brealize_VERB%20her%20aims%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

He **took** aim and fired. I **took** careful aim. It did not **achieve** its principal aims.

**have** an aim, **fulfil** one's aim, **pursue** one's aims, **set out** the aims, **steady** one's aim,

It is not wise to say 'She met her aims'. But we can say 'She met her needs'. 'She met her requirements.'
meet one's deadline, meet one's target, meet conditions,

Comment: This only addresses the question in the last line and it does so without any explanation.

Answer (score -2):

**aim** is a verb and I am inclined to say further that it is first a verb and has later (perhaps recently) taken on the noun function of "goal." To me, "aim" as a noun, especially plural possessive, like *her aims*, smacks of buzzword neologism. But anyway.

If you *take aim* at a *target* and *launch* something or *drive* something or someone towards it [the *target*, or *goal*], you are either *accurate* and you **hit your aim**, or you are *inaccurate* and you *miss*. But it might be safe to just employ something along the lines of, "*She achieved her goals*" or "*He met his target*".

Comment: Aim has been a noun for a long time. HG Wells said of Sydney Webb (husband of Beatrice) that "his aim is rather persuasion than truth", in his "Experiment in Autobiography" (1934).

Comment: @Michael Harvey In those days, buzzwords were still omnibuzzwords.

Comment: “aim” is a noun and a verb; according to Merriam-Webster, the earliest-known verb usage dates from the 14th century, and the earliest-known noun usage dates from the 15th century [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aim]